# How do I drop supplementary groups in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix, privileges

I have an executable that's `ug+s` to a non-root user and group. I would like it to leave all the supplementary groups it originally had behind. Is there a way to make this happen? It doesn't look like the `setgroups` call allows you to do this if you're not root. And when I try it, I get `EPERM`.

It seems like there ought to be a way to lose privileges you previously possessed.

Comment: What gives you the impression that `setgroups` cannot be used to do this?

Comment: @zwol - Because I tried it, and it fails with `EPERM`. Basically, you only get to make that call if you have CAP_SETGID, and since the program starting the set{u,g}id process is non-privileged and the user/group being set{u,g}id'ed to is also non-privileged, no go.

Comment: Oh, huh. That ... might actually mean there's no way to do it. (I'm not aware of any other system call that changes the supplementary groups list.) Do you have the ability to try the program on a different kernel, like one of the BSDs? "I can do this on FooBSD" is going to be an easier sell to the kernel devs than "there's never been a way to do this but I want one".

Comment: @zwol - Turns out it's the way it is for a reason, and if FooBSD isn't that way, it should be: https://lwn.net/Articles/626665/

Comment: Ugh, I should have thought of that.  Thanks.

Comment: @Omnifarious: You do need either the CAP_SETUID or CAP_SETGID capability (which you can set for the specific executable using the `setcap` utility), or set the binary setuid or setgid root. I've used both approaches successfully. To set supplementary groups based on an user name, use `initgroups()`. To keep things secure, I recommend putting this in a separate wrapper program, that examines the caller privileges/identity, stats and checks the target binary (path specified at compile time), and if acceptable, executes it as the desired user.

Comment: @NominalAnimal - That may not be an option for us. And since I'm creating a new user namespace immediately after becoming the new user, I don't know that it's needed in this case anyway. Those other groups are basically all mapped to nobody. Perhaps you should write that up in an answer so I don't have to answer my own question here.

Comment: @Omnifarious: If you describe your findings and the reasons why you chose your solution, that would definitely be the better answer here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "A process without CAP_SETGID can't.". And it is [by design that setgroups can't be used to remove groups when the process has no privileges](https://lwn.net/Articles/626665/). The previous link is to an excellent LWN article detailing why not.

In my particular case, since I'm immediately creating a user namespace, those supplementary groups get mapped to 'nobody' anyway. And so it isn't very important. If it is important, you can use [`setcap(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) to set capabilities on a wrapper executable that checks that it's being run by the expected user with the expected group permissions and then drops the groups and drops CAP_SETGID and runs the executable you really want to run. The command you would use to do this is:

```
sudo setcap cap_setgid+ep wrapper_exe
```

Be careful though, it's now possible that someone who has a shell on your system can use that executable to run some sort of privilege escalation attack if you did not write it very carefully.

Comment: Although, I am not sure the second para is correct. The point of the kernel fix in the linked article is that for unprivileged (non-CAP_SETGID) users "it essentially become impossible to (1) play tricks with mappings to drop groups".  So I am not convinced the supplementary groups are getting remapped to 'nobody'.

Comment: @sourcejedi - Note the 'in my particular case' qualifier there.

Comment: If your kernel follows different rules than those in the linked source, it would be much clearer if you specified that. If your kernel follows the same rules, what is the special condition in these rules in which "those supplementary groups get mapped to 'nobody' anyway"?

Comment: @sourcejedi - Those aren't special rules. That is what happens when you create a user namespace when you aren't root. All uids but the one for you get mapped to the nobody, and the same for all gids but the one for you.

Comment: When you look from inside the namespace, the extra groups appear as the nobody. But when you look from outside the namespace, the process has not lost its supplementary groups.  Therefore, *if* the process still has visibility of an object which in reality (the outer namespace) belongs to one of those groups, the permissions of that group will still apply to the actions taken by the process. That might grant more permissions over the object - or it might grant *less* permissions.  The latter is why this approach is required.

Comment: @sourcejedi - Oh. Yeah, you're probably right. :-( Now I'm worrying about security problems in something I wrote over a year ago.